# Deleting rows by multiple joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to delete the rows by joining the multiple tables as you can see but it throws me an error:

```
DELETE FROM Reg INNER JOIN
            RegDoc ON Reg.RegId = RegDoc.RegId INNER JOIN
            Doc ON RegDoc.DocId = Doc.DocId
WHERE Doc.Name LIKE N'%Title%'
```

getting error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.

Answer (score 7):

**The correct syntax is**

```
DELETE [ FROM ] { <object> } 
[ FROM <table_source>]
[ WHERE { <search_condition> } ]
```

**Applied to your example this would become**

```
DELETE FROM Reg 
FROM  Reg
      INNER JOIN RegDoc ON Reg.RegId = RegDoc.RegId 
      INNER JOIN Doc ON RegDoc.DocId = Doc.DocId
WHERE Doc.Name LIKE N'%Title%'
```

*Note the **two** references to the `Reg` table*

**This can be shortened further by aliasing** (although there's little need in this case)

```
DELETE FROM r
FROM  Reg r
      INNER JOIN RegDoc ON r.RegId = RegDoc.RegId 
      INNER JOIN Doc ON RegDoc.DocId = Doc.DocId
WHERE Doc.Name LIKE N'%Title%'
```

---

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx) Example

```
DELETE FROM Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory 
FROM Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory AS spqh
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson AS sp
ON spqh.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID
WHERE sp.SalesYTD > 2500000.00;
```

Comment: Oughtta' be `DELETE reg FROM ...` no?

Comment: @Farray - `DELETE FROM` is correct but the first `FROM` may indeed be ommitted. It's kind of like writing out `LEFT OUTER JOIN` where the `OUTER` is also redundant but I still tend to write it out completely.

Comment: The first `from` in `delete from t1 from Table1 as t1` is optional, but will work just fine

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
DELETE 
FROM Reg 
FROM Reg 
INNER JOIN
            RegDoc ON Reg.RegId = RegDoc.RegId INNER JOIN
            Doc ON RegDoc.DocId = Doc.DocId
WHERE Doc.Name LIKE N'%Title%'
```

or more clear, IMHO:

```
DELETE Reg 
FROM Reg 
INNER JOIN RegDoc 
  ON Reg.RegId = RegDoc.RegId 
INNER JOIN Doc 
  ON RegDoc.DocId = Doc.DocId
WHERE Doc.Name LIKE N'%Title%'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
DELETE Reg
FROM Reg 
INNER JOIN RegDoc ON Reg.RegId = RegDoc.RegId 
INNER JOIN Doc ON RegDoc.DocId = Doc.DocId
WHERE Doc.Name LIKE N'%Title%'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an alias, though it's clearer if you use an alias that's different from the table name:

```
DELETE  r 
FROM    Reg as r
INNER JOIN RegDoc rd ON r.RegId = rd.RegId 
INNER JOIN Doc d ON rd.DocId = d.DocId
```

You can actually `delete rd` and `delete d` too.

Answer (score 2):

A bit different approach than the other answers (which are all good)

```
DELETE FROM Reg
WHERE Reg.RegID IN (SELECT RegDoc.RegId
                    FROM RegDoc
                      INNER JOIN Doc 
                        ON RegDoc.DocId = Doc.DocId
                    WHERE Doc.Name LIKE N'%Title%')
```